# Why is there a space between letter and point? T-SQL bug?

Tags: t-sql

Why is there a space between letter and point?

```
DECLARE @I1 int = 1;

SELECT CASE WHEN @I1 > 26 
    THEN CHAR(64 + (@I1 / 26)) + CHAR(64 + (@I1 % 26)) 
    ELSE CHAR(64 + @I1) 
END + '.'
```

Result:
A .

Answer (score 2):

Aha, this is converted to char(2) type. Okay RTRIM solved problem!

```
DECLARE @I1 int = 1;

SELECT RTRIM(CASE WHEN @I1 > 26 
    THEN CHAR(64 + (@I1 / 26)) + CHAR(64 + (@I1 % 26)) 
    ELSE CHAR(64 + @I1) END) + '.'
```

Comment: Tip: A handy way to check the data type of an expression is [`SQL_Variant_Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): `select SQL_Variant_Property( Char(64) + Char(65), 'BaseType' ) as BaseType, SQL_Variant_Property( Char(64) + Char(65), 'MaxLength' ) as MaxLength;`.